# Marshalling safearray of safearray from VARIANT in C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, native, marshalling

I'm trying to call a function in .NET from a native library, like this:

```c
typedef int (WINAPI* TGetAllObjects)(int hModel, VARIANT& objects);
```

If you call it in the C++ client, the debugger shows that objects are a safearray of `VARIANT`, and each `VARIANT` is a safearray of `BSTR`.

I tried to implement as follows in C#:

```cs
public delegate TRetCode TGetAllObjects(int hModel, 
    [Out,In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT )] ref MyStruct[] objects);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
    public string[] Objects;
}
```

When calling the method, it gives an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: "Specified array was not of the expected type."

Please tell me how to properly organize data marshalling in such a situation.

Comment: Sounds like you've got an array of arrays of strings? Maybe you need `[Out,In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT )] object[][] objects` Don't think you should use `ref`

Comment: @Charlieface I tried. An exception is thrown
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: "Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': There is no marshaling support for nested arrays."

Comment: Ok, what about `object[]`?

Comment: @Charlieface No error occurs. But the passed array remains empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate int TGetAllObjects(int hModel, ref object objects);
```

and see EXACTLY what you receive. The `objects` variable is a `VARIANT`, not a `SAFEARRAY`. The `VARIANT& objects` *contains* the `SAFEARRAY`, it *isn't* a `SAFEARRAY`.

Then inside your code you can check its type and cast it.

Ah and note the `CallingConvention` (`WINAPI` is `StdCall`).

I've made some tests and it seems the basic `VARIANT` "container" is passed correctly. I'll say the truth, I consider a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT` that are `SAFEARRAY`s of `BSTR` a weapon that should be included in the banned list by the Geneva Convention.

Some more tests make me think that my solution is the easyest one. I wasn't able to accept/pass directly a `object[]` or a `string[]`, and the received `objects` is a `object[]` where each element is a `string[]`. Something like:

```
var objects = new object[] { new string[] { "A", "B" }, new string[] { "C", "D" } };
```

**Your "casting" problem**

`SAFEARRAY` can have the index of the first element `!= 0` (this to support VB that uses 1-based arrays, arrays, where the first element is 1). .NET does support this in the category "strange arrays". Multidimensional arrays (`string[1, 2]`) and non-0 based arrays are in this category, and they are a pain to handle. Non-zero based arrays more so.

Code to convert the array in your case (where with "convert" I mean: copy it to a standard .NET array of arrays):

```
object[] castedObjects = (object[])objects;
string[][] strings = new string[castedObjects.Length][];

for (int i = 0; i < castedObjects.Length; i++)
{
    Array ar = (Array)castedObjects[i];
    string[] ar2 = new string[ar.Length];
    Array.Copy(ar, ar2, ar2.Length);
    strings[i] = ar2;
}
```

Comment: StdCall is the default so the attribute is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 
How do I get the internal array? Cast to string[ ] doesn't work (
Screensjot: https://prnt.sc/y1jha8

Comment: Understood) You need to cast to Array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Egorosh You have a `object[]`. That is different from a `string[]`. Each element is a `string[]`. It is exactly like the example I gave at the end. You can simply extract the `string[]` with a `for (int i = 0; i < castcastObjects.Length; i++) { string[] temp = (string[])castcastObjects[i]; }` or you can `var strings = Array.ConvertAll((object[])objects, x => (string[])x)`

Comment: @xanatos Cast to string [] throw System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'." Cast to Array worked)

Comment: @Egorosh Ok... They are using "VB-style" arrays... they are indexed 1...4 instead of 0...3. They are a pain. They must be translated to C#...

Comment: @Egorosh I've simplified a little the copy code. You can use `Array.Copy`